# Where is the CSV gem in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, csv, ruby-on-rails-4

I’m using Rails 4.2 with Ruby 2.3.0.  I want to use the CSV parsing library, which according to the documentation is part of the core Ruby distribution — https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/csv/rdoc/CSV.html .  However, when I put this on my page

```
csv = CSV.parse(text_content, :headers => true)
```

it results in this error

```
Error during processing: uninitialized constant CsvToActivityConverterService::CSV
```

Do I need another gem to include the CSV library in my Rails project?

Comment: as the answer indicates below. You should be able to just require it to use it.  To do this application wide add it to the `config/application.rb` inside the `class Application < Rails::Application` or if you just want it one time you can require it wherever you're using it (i.e. in the console just enter `require 'csv'` then run your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to `require 'csv'` to use it!